# The difference between dcbf and dccivac arm instructions

Tags: c, flush, invalidation

Context:

I currently want to flush my descriptor to read the proper status bits.
Can someone explain to me if I should be using dcbf or dccivac instruction? I fail to understand the right difference between them.

Thank you in advance :)

I have tried experimenting dcbf and dccivac both. I understand that dcbf flushes my address from cache but dccivac also marks the address as invalid. Please rectify my understanding.

Comment: `dcbf` is a powerPC instruction. I did hot hear about ARM one

Comment: "I currently want to flush my descriptor to read the proper status bits." Can you provide context for this?  What kind of "descriptor"?  Presumably you're communicating with some kind of memory-mapped hardware; what is it and what are its characteristics?  What version of ARM architecture?  In some cases you may be able to mark this address as device memory, in which case it will be uncached and you don't need explicit cache management.